# Plotly.js , How to increase the area devoted for the text in plotly.js Bar x axis?

Tags: javascript, plotly

How to increase the area devoted for the text in plotly.js Bar x axis?
CUrrently, the values of x axis are "text very long and longer 1", "text very long and longer 2", "text very long and longer 3".
After plotting, i am getting the image where the text is cutted and remains only "text very lon", "text very lon", "text very lon".

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [margin](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-margin) to manually define the borders of your graph, see the snippet below.

```js
var layout = {
  autosize: false,
  width: 600,
  height: 500,
  margin: {
    l: 50,
    r: 350,
    b: 200,
    t: 50,
    pad: 4
  }
};
var data = [{
  x: ["text very long and longer 1", "extremely long text 2", "extremely long text with some extra characters 3", "the longest text, probably most useless x-axis caption ever 4"],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'scatter'
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDivNoLayout', data);
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id='myDivNoLayout'></div>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```